# How to unserialize data from SQL query and parse them in JSON

Tags: mysql, json, wordpress, serialization, metadata

I have the above PHP code in order to fecth my data from my MYSQL DB and parse them into a JSON.

```
$BusinessProductsData ='';
        $sql = "SELECT t1.meta_value, t1.post_id FROM `f2st_postmeta` AS t1 
                INNER JOIN
                (SELECT post_title AS post_title, ID FROM `f2st_posts` WHERE post_type='restaurants' and post_status='publish') AS t2
                ON t1.post_id=t2.ID
                WHERE t1.meta_key='foodbakery_menu_items'";

        mysqli_set_charset($dbConnection, "utf8");

        $result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $sql);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $json_array[] = $row;
        }

        $BusinessProductsData = json_encode($json_array);
        echo $BusinessProductsData;
```

Unfortunately, meta_value has serialized values like this one
`{"meta_value":"a:2:{i:0;a:7:{s:15:\"menu_item_title\";s:89:\"Dr. Scholl Fungal Nail Treatment \u03a3\u03cd\u03c3\u03c4\u03b7\u03bc\u03b1 \u0391\u03bd\u03c4\u03b9\u03bc\u03b5\u03c4\u03ce\u03c0\u03b9\u03c3\u03b7\u03c2 \u039c\u03c5\u03ba\u03ae\u03c4\u03c9\u03bd\";s:15:\"restaurant_menu\";s:27:\"\u0395\u03af\u03b4\u03b7 \u03a6\u03c1\u03bf\u03bd\u03c4\u03af\u03b4\u03b1\u03c2\";s:21:\"menu_item_description\";s:0:\"\";s:14:\"menu_item_icon\";s:5:\"16665\";s:15:\"menu_item_nutri\";s:0:\"\";s:15:\"menu_item_price\";s:5:\"15.12\";s:15:\"menu_item_extra\";s:0:\"\";}i:1;a:7:{s:15:\"menu_item_title\";s:61:\"Optima Aloe Pura Aloe Vera Gel 200ml \u0396\u03b5\u03bb \u0391\u03bb\u03cc\u03b7 \u0392\u03ad\u03c1\u03b1\";s:15:\"restaurant_menu\";s:25:\"\u0395\u03af\u03b4\u03b7 \u039f\u03bc\u03bf\u03c1\u03c6\u03af\u03b1\u03c2\";s:21:\"menu_item_description\";s:0:\"\";s:14:\"menu_item_icon\";s:5:\"16666\";s:15:\"menu_item_nutri\";s:0:\"\";s:15:\"menu_item_price\";s:4:\"6.86\";s:15:\"menu_item_extra\";s:0:\"\";}}","post_id":"16220"},{"meta_value":"a:0:{}","post_id":"16331"}`

How can I unserialize meta_value?

Comment: `unserialize()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: I've been through unserialize() function but not with success...And I don't know why. Is it because only "meta_value" column is serialized and not "post_id"? Is it beacause it can't be implemented in my PHP code? Can you please be more spesific to my code?

Comment: You need to run `unserialize()` on the value in each column; it won't work on the entire row/query. So in your while loop, you can run `unserialize( $row['meta_value'] )`, which will give you an object containing all the data that was serialized in that field.

Comment: That helped me a lot...You are right. Now I have this `[[],[],[],[],[{"menu_item_title":"Dr. Scholl Fungal Nail Treatment \u03a3\u03cd\u03c3\u03c4\u03b7\u03bc\u03b1 \u0391\u03bd\u03c4\u03b9\u03bc\u03b5\u03c4\u03ce\u03c0\u03b9\u03c3\u03b7\u03c2 \u039c\u03c5\u03ba\u03ae\u03c4\u03c9\u03bd","restaurant_menu":"\u0395\u03af\u03b4\u03b7 \u03a6\u03c1\u03bf\u03bd\u03c4\u03af\u03b4\u03b1\u03c2","menu_item_description":"","menu_item_icon":"16665","menu_item_nutri":"","menu_item_price":"15.12","menu_item_extra":""}` Although 'post_id' has gone I think that you put me in the right way...

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Try and format this as code in the question itself, not in comments where it's really hard to read. You can format code by indenting with four spaces.